# What does Lumosity's Flexibility measure?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, brain-training

One of the Lumosity BPI measurements is termed Flexibility.  What is this measuring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How valid is Lumosity's Brain Performance Index and what normative information is available?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/how-valid-is-lumositys-brain-performance-index-and-what-normative-information-i) which covers much of the same stuff but with a much more precise question.

Comment: I would like to see a study of Lumosity's flexibility measure and the effects of risperdal on the brain. I began Lumosity in January 2013 while on 3 mg of risperdal. As I began performing lumosity, my score remained fairly flat until I went through stepdown dosages all the way from 3 mg to 0 mg daily. My Lumosity flexibility score increased from 800 to 1300. You can see the score jump after July, when I hit 0 mg of risperdal. I am currently back on Risperdal and will be tracking my flexibility score as I go back to 1 mg of risperdal.

Comment: @Keith Welcome to CogSci. I converted your answer to a comment, since it didn't answer the question. In the process unfortunately part of it was dropped due to comment length restrictions. Please read the faq to find out what constitutes a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe they are attempting to measure [Cognitive Flexibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_flexibility) (there is a citation linking to Lumosity at the very end of the article).

From the Wiki article:

> ***Cognitive flexibility*** has been described as the mental ability to switch between thinking about two different concepts, and to think about multiple concepts simultaneously....
>
> Other terms for *cognitive flexibility* include mental flexibility, shifting, mental set or cognitive shifting, task switching/shifting, and attention switching/shifting....
>
> Most commonly, *cognitive flexibility* refers to the mental ability to adjust thinking or attention in response to changing goals and/or environmental stimuli....
>
> Lastly, the ability to simultaneously consider two aspects of an object, idea, or situation at one point in time refers to *cognitive flexibility*. According to this definition, when sorting cards based on specific rules, children are considered *cognitively flexible* rules if they can sort cards based on the color of the objects and type of objects on the card simultaneously. Similarly, *cognitive flexibility* has been defined as having the understanding and awareness of all possible options and alternatives simultaneously within any given situation.

I hope that helps!